# How to transfer learning or fine tune tensorflow lite tflite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, yolo, transfer-learning, darknet

I have a darknet yolov4 model that is converted to tflite file and trained by COCO dataset for object detection.
I want to train that for my traffic sign dataset. (GTSDB)
How should I do that for my tflite file?

I don't want to do that in darknet and then convert to tflite. I want to transfer learning directly from tflite file.

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/deeppicar-part-6-963334b2abe0